# Why Queue is not an option in Developer Edition Org Process Builder Flow Update Record Action?

Tags: managed-package, process-builder, visual-workflow, visual-flows, queue

Why Queue is not an option in Developer Edition Org Process Builder Flow Update Record Action?

I am creating a package where I set an owner of record to Queue.

While on usual sandbox I can select a Queue option as value provider for Owner Id in Org Process Builder Flow Update Record Action, 
[image]
when I try to do the same on managed package development environment, there is no such option.
[image]

Is there any specific reason why this is not an option in package development organization?

Is there any other workaround to use trigger and apex code? Is there any declarative way to solve this problem without using triggers and apex classes?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is difference between Winter 18 and Summer 17 release.

Page 435 of

https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/210/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter18_release_notes.pdf

says

> Quickly Reference Specific Users and Queues in Your Processes Say
>   hello to a more intuitive way of referencing users in your processes.
>   Instead of manually entering a user ID, simply search for that user by
>   name. You can also search for queues. This change applies to both
>   Lightning Experience and Salesforce Classic. The ID and Reference
>   value types didn’t go anywhere. You can still enter the user or queue
>   ID manually or reference a field value from a related record. Note:
>   User and Queue aren’t available in criteria or action rows that were
>   created before Winter ’18. To use one of these new types in an
>   existing process, create a new row. Example: When you configure an
>   action to create a case, you can choose from these value types for
>   Owner ID. We’re assuming that you have at least one queue enabled for
>   cases. • ID • Reference • Global Constant • Formula • User • Queue To
>   assign the case to a queue, choose Queue under Type, and start typing
>   under Value to find the right case.
>   [image]